# In bxslider i want to add a class on current slide

Tags: jquery, slider, bxslider

I want to add an extra class to the current visible slide, i dont have so much knowledge of jquery i'm trying it by following code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        pager: 'true'
     });
 $(currentSlide).addClass('active-slide');
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://bxslider.com/options

```
    var slider=$('#slider1').bxSlider({
     pager: 'true',
   onBeforeSlide: function(currentSlide, totalSlides, currentSlideHtmlObject){
        $('.pager').removeClass('active-slide');   
         $(currentSlideHtmlObject).addClass('active-slide');
 //     $('#sddf').html('<p class="check">Slide index ' + currentSlide + ' of ' + totalSlides + ' total slides has completed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: so how would i apply a class to currentSlide, I m sorry i dont know jquery so much. Please tell the full code i need to copy paste.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mL4xq/1/ this is the code, in JS area first there is code of the plugin and at the bottom there is custom code

Comment: thank  you so much xMen but there are few issues, when clicked for next slide the class from the inactive slide should be removed also on the first slide i need the active-slide class.

Comment: try giving `$('.pager').removeClass('active-slide');`

Comment: For latest versions: At http://bxslider.com/options appears the params for onSlideBefore: ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex). Not the mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 10):

To add class on the first visible slide you have to call onSliderLoad. Then you continue adding and removing active-slide class with onSlideAfter call.

```
onSlideAfter: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
    $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.bxslider>li').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 1).addClass('active-slide')
},
onSliderLoad: function () {
    $('.bxslider>li').eq(1).addClass('active-slide')
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dariodev/587pqsct/

Comment: onSliderLoad should have .eq(0) instead of .eq(1)

Comment: No, this is actually just fine. Someone edited my answer and broke it. I returned the original answer because it works properly. Please check before edit https://jsfiddle.net/dariodev/587pqsct/

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
$('#slider1 ul').bxSlider({
    pager: 'true',
    onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex) {     
      $('#slider1').find('.bx-viewport').find('ul').children().eq(currentIndex + 1).addClass('active-slide');
    },
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement){
      $('#slider1').find('.bx-viewport').find('ul').children().removeClass('active-slide');
      $slideElement.addClass('active-slide');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ntx6sag/3/)

Answer (score -1):

its 100% working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 280,
                slideMargin: 20,
                useCSS: false,
                autoHover: false,
                speed: 2000,
                oneToOneTouch: true,
                pager: 'true',
                onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex) {     
                  $('.bxslider1').find('.bx-viewport').find('ul').children().eq(currentIndex + 1).addClass('active-slide');
                },
                onSlideBefore: function($slideElement){
                  $('.bxslider1').find('.bx-viewport').find('ul').children().removeClass('active-slide');
                  $slideElement.addClass('active-slide');
                }
            });

        });
```