# add class to next element jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I have created a vertical slider and I want the classes to move onto the next div on click (next) and previous on click (prev)

here is my code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLq7brq1/)

```
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+1)").addClass('noBlur');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+2)").addClass('Blur1');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+3)").addClass('Blur2');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n)").addClass('Blur3');

$("a.bx-next").click(function(){
   $(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+1)").next().addClass('noBlur');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+2)").next().addClass('Blur1');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+3)").next().addClass('Blur2');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n)").next().addClass('Blur3');
});


$("a.bx-prev").click(function(){
   $(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+1)").prev().addClass('noBlur');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+2)").prev().addClass('Blur1');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+3)").prev().addClass('Blur2');
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n)").prev().addClass('Blur3');
});
```

Comment: fiddle seems to work for me with `Chrome`, what is wrong with yours?

Answer (score 1):

Classes seem to be colliding with each other. I'd suggest cleaning current classes before adding the 'blur' classes, e.g. :

```
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+1)").next().removeClass().addClass('bxslider-inner').addClass('noBlur');
```

etc... Problem is it only works for he first click on the button, as

```
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(4n+1)").next()
```

Will always be the same element. You now need to find a way to fetch the right elements on your click function.

Some elements here : [In bxslider i want to add a class on current slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745083/in-bxslider-i-want-to-add-a-class-on-current-slide)

Comment: Looking at this again is it possible make the first child act as last child on click so the the second child acts as the first and so on...

Comment: Maybe you can create a variable i and increment/decrement it on button clicks, then go fetch the divs you want with

$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(i)").next()
$(".bxslider-inner:nth-child(i+1)").next()

and so on

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be on the same level of the DOM tree, so you would use:

```
$(this).next().click();
```